# jQuery Maximum call stack size exceeded, when focusing on next input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Newb here.

I have a form:

```
<form name="code" action="*" method="post" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" name="code" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" class="a">
<input type="text" name="code" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" class="b">
<input type="text" name="code" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" class="c">
<input type="text" name="code" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" class="d">
<input type="text" name="code" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" class="e">
<input type="text" name="code" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off" class="f last">
<button type="submit" class="full" value="" disabled="disabled"></button>
</form>
```

And my jQuery is:

```
$("form").on("keyup change paste focusin", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var a=$(this).find("input[type='text'].a");
    var b=$(this).find("input[type='text'].b");
    var c=$(this).find("input[type='text'].c");
    var d=$(this).find("input[type='text'].d");
    var e=$(this).find("input[type='text'].e");
    var f=$(this).find("input[type='text'].f");

    a.val(a.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g,""));
    b.val(b.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g,""));
    c.val(c.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g,""));
    d.val(d.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g,""));
    e.val(e.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g,""));
    f.val(f.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g,""));

    if (a.val().length == 1) {
        a.next(b).focus();
    }
    if (b.val().length == 1) {
        b.next(c).focus();
    }
    ...

});
```

What I am tryin to do is, when field `a` was filled in. I want to move on to field `b` and so on.

Now what happens is when the `IF` condition gets triggered, it throws a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error.

What am I doing wrong here?

And is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: you have "focusin" as event listener for your form yet keep giving focus to a or b inside the event handler, which is causing the issue

Comment: Your focus() method seems to retrigger your method attached to the listeners every loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `.focus()` with jQuery will cause relevant event handlers to run immediately, and since you're doing it from inside the "focusin" handler you end up with infinite recursion. I've always solved that by doing the `.focus()` operation in a timeout:

```
if (a.val().length == 1) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        a.next(b).focus();
    }, 1);
}
```

Even without the recursion problem, you have to let the current "focus" work finish up before redirecting focus to another element.